# Detect if an image view is rotated in degrees

Tags: java, android

I made an image rotate 30 degrees every time I click a button. Is there any way I can detect when the image is rotated 30 degrees after?

Here's a better explanation:
If I click a button, it's going to rotate 30 degrees. If I click it again, it will rotate another 30 degrees, so it's 60 degrees in total. I would like to know if the image is rotated 30 and 60

[The next icon is what will rotate the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8OmT.png)

[I can't type the code, so here is an image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FXl0.png)

I tried the following code:

```
float rotation = image_circle.getRotation();
        if (rotation == 31) {
            image_circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Store the rotation angle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the rotation value and then increment on each rotation. Something like this:

```
//Rotate image by 30 degrees on each button click
rotationDegrees += 30f
image_circle.rotation = rotationDegrees

// Check if image is rotated by 30 and 60 degrees
if (rotationDegrees == 30f) {
    image_circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else if (rotationDegrees == 60f) {
   image_circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```